# How to embed hashes into an array and iterate through those hashes in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I wanted to create several hashes within an array and iterate through that array to populate the different key values.

```
participant = {
"participant_name" => "",
"cupcakes_sold" => 0, 
"cakes_sold" => 0,
"cupcakes_left" => 0,
"cakes_left" => 0
}

participants = Array.new(4)

#loops through 4 times to populate hash with values  
participants.each do |participant| 
    puts "\nPlease enter participant name:  "
    participant["participant_name"] = gets.chomp
    puts "\nHow many cupcakes did " + participant.fetch("participant_name") + " sell?"
    participant["cupcakes_sold"] = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "\nHow many does " + participant.fetch("participant_name") + " have left?"
    participant["cupcakes_left"] = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "\nHow many cakes did " + participant.fetch("participant_name") + " sell?"
    participant["cakes_sold"] = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "\nHow many does " +  participant.fetch("participant_name") + " have left?"
    participant["cakes_left"] = gets.chomp.to_i
    participants << participant
end

puts participants
```

So, I'm not sure how to populate the array with a hash value. I'm also not sure how to iterate through the embedded hashes in the array. I also get an error for participants = new Array(4). Am I instantiating that correctly?

**I think to populate the array, I can add participant << participants to my loop?**

Comment: Try `participants = new Array(4)){ {} }`. Note the outer `{ }` are a block, and the inner `{}` construct a Hash literal. That seeds your 4 array items with the correct values to take your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do that.

```
4.times.map do
  participant = {} 
  puts "\nPlease enter participant name"
  name = gets.chomp
  participant["participant_name"] = name
  ["cupcakes", "cakes"].each do |item|
    puts "How many #{item} did #{name} sell?"  
    participant["#{item}_sold"] = gets.to_i
    puts "How many does #{name} have left?"  
    participant["#{item}_left"] = gets.to_i
  end
  participant
end
  #=> [{ "participant_name"=>"Billy-Bob", "cupcakes_sold"=>46, "cupcakes_left=>12",
  #      "cakes_sold=>12, "cakes_left=>2 },
  #    { "participant_name"=>"Trixy", "cupcakes_sold"=>112, "cupcakes_left=>0",
  #      "cakes_sold=>85, "cakes_left=>0 },
  #    { "participant_name"=>"Bub", "cupcakes_sold"=>2, "cupcakes_left=>104",
  #      "cakes_sold=>1, "cakes_left=>18 },
  #    { "participant_name"=>"Wilma", "cupcakes_sold"=>64, "cupcakes_left=>"31",
  #      "cakes_sold=>18, "cakes_left=>9 }]
```

Note that `chomp` in `"3\n".chomp.to_i #=> 3` is not needed: `"3\n".to_i #=> 3`.

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem is that when I initiated my array of size 4, I created an array with four elements that were nil. When it called inspect on my array (participants.inspect), I saw that the first four values were actually nil and my loop was adding on to these nil values in the array. **So, this time I didn't set a size when initiating my array outside of the loop.**

My solution (imitated what Cary Swoveland did):

```
 #allocates new empty array of participants
participants = Array.new() 

#loops 4 times to populate embedded hash with values 
num_participants.times do
#creates the empty hash of bakesale participants
  participant = Hash.new
  puts "\n\e[36mParticipant name:\e[0m"
  name = gets.chomp
  participant["participant_name"] = name
  ["cookies", "cakes"].each do |item|
    sleep 0.25
    puts "\e[36mHow many #{item} did \e[0m #{name.capitalize} \e[36m sell (enter number)?\e[0m"  
    participant["#{item}_sold"] = gets.to_i
    sleep 0.25
    puts "\e[36mHow many does \e[0m #{name.capitalize} \e[36m have left (enter number)?\e[0m"  
    participant["#{item}_left"] = gets.to_i
  end
#loops through 4 times to add each participant to participants array
    participants << participant
  sleep 0.5
end
```